# Is there a way to create POJO from Java class?

Tags: java

I have the bunch of Java classes. I need to create simple POJOs of just the fields from Java classes. There is a way to create POJOs from JSON but I need directly from Java classes.

Java class may have logical methods and constructed based upon different things. My goal is just to hold the state in POJOs and send it over the network and deserialize in same set of POJOs.

Comment: What do you think a POJO is? It means "Plain Old Java Object".

Comment: yes this is a confusing question. A POJO is a Java object. what you want is a JSON library like others have mentioned. Are you using some web framework?

Comment: You can copy the data, but not 'logical methods', data and logic should not be mixed inside one POJO class, especially when it's going to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Use some JSON library.

For ex. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

You could choose what fields to serialize or not using `transient` identifier.

Apart from that these libraries offer much more and definitely all the requirements you specified.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @luk2302 I disagree: it is offering (or attempting to offer) a solution, rather than asking for clarification. It could be expanded and improved to explain why this is what OP should use, sure.

Comment: added some details to better help op.

Comment: @AndyTurner Then again, the OP already states he is aware of JSON.

Comment: @daniu then the answer is not useful. But it's still not a comment.

Comment: instead of adding link please add required code or details only. Most of time links are deleted by original user.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize Java classes just fine, no need to strip them down to their fields (which is what it sounds like you want).

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private int myInt;
    private String myString;

    public MyClass(int mi, String ms) {
        myInt = mi; myString = ms;
    }

    public String doStuff() { return String.format("%s %d", myString, myInt); }
}
```

Code for serialization:

```
MyClass toSerialize = new MyClass(5, "Test");
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(getNetworkOutstream())) {
   out.writeObject(toSerialize);
}
```

Code to deserialize:

```
try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(getNetworkInStream())) {
    MyClass received = (MyClass) in.readObject();
}
```

The `doStuff` method is not in the way if that's what you're thinking.

Caveat is that all fields need to also be `Serializable` (or primitives).

Comment: I don't want to create instance by putting values and then serialize.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to programmatically parse all those classes and generate POJOs for them, then you can use libraries like Antlr, JavaCC or JavaParser to analyse sources and then generate and save the new POJOs.